# AS3 Getting to Control Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am building a Flash Game, I am doing this:

MainStage, with 11 frames
Mainstage Loads > Lobby.swf (1 frame)
Lobby Loads > Arrows.swf (1 frame)

I just want to control the main Stage from Arrows.swf , get the current frame, right arrow mainStage.current frame + 1, left arrow mainStage.current frame -1

I have tried the parent/child method

```
this.parent.parent
parent.parent
this.root
parent.root
```

every combination, I am also tracing and when I finally hit the mainStage it is saying cannot convert Stage to Display Object which I understand.

but how can I just get current frame of the "mainstage" needle and control it with gotoAndPlay or other such methods ?

Comment: Have you tried to bubble the event?

Comment: This way of thinking is so AS2...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

I didn't control the main stage what I did was, I reduced the main stage layer in the lobby layer when I load the left and right arrow I attach an event listener for a custom event.

In the arrows movie I have written a function to dispatch the event here are the lines of code I used

in the "main" stage of the movie you want to control:

```
//ball loader prep and load
var ballLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var ballRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("lobbyBalls.swf");
ballLoader.load(ballRequest);
ballLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ballsLoaded);

function ballsLoaded(event:Event):void{
    trace("ball Loader complete");
    ballLoader.x = 50;
    ballLoader.y = 200;
    stage.addChild(ballLoader);
    ballLoader.content.addEventListener("Previous", ctrlPrevFrame);
    ballLoader.content.addEventListener("Next", ctrlNextFrame);
}
```

In the movie from which you want to control

```
import flash.events.Event;

leftArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevEvent);
rightArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextEvent);

function prevEvent(event:Event):void{
    trace("prev");
    dispatchEvent(new Event("Previous", true));
}

function nextEvent(event:Event):void{
    trace("next");
    dispatchEvent(new Event("Next", true));
}
```

Thanks anyways....

Comment: Please make sure you mark your own answer as correct when it is eligible (I believe the time on that is currently 2 days after answer is made). This will effectively close this question, as well as help out your own reputation score (which allows you more privileges on the site)